# uncoupled transport equation of (U) and another coupled linear pde, does $U$ decay?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, transport-equation

[image]

Let $C = 1$ and $\gamma = 1$. and the initial conditions as $U(t=0) = e^{cos(2\pi x)}$ (periodic boundary) and $V(t=0) = 0$. Now I'm getting two numerical solutions. One models the $U$ as a transported wave moving to the right, the other models $U$ as a decaying wave over time. Which one is right?

Comment: As shown in @JJacquelin's answer,  $U$ does not decay: it is only transported / shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+C\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=0$$
There is no difficulty to analytically solve this PDE thanks to the method of characteristics or other method. The general solution is :
$$U(t,x)=F(x-Ct)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.

Initial condition : $U(0,x)=e^{\cos(2\pi x)}=F(x-0t)$
$$F(x)=e^{\cos(2\pi x)}$$
Now the function $F$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where the variable is not $x$ but is $(x-Ct)$.
$$\boxed{U(x,t)=e^{\cos\left(2\pi (x-Ct)\right)}}$$
So the exact model for $U(t,x)$ is determined and this answers to your question.

Comment: Thank you. It confirmed what I was suspecting. Another way to show that u has a unique transported solution is via the uniqueness of the Fourier series representation. With the initial condition for v given, it’s a unique initial value problem

Comment: However many people on my course disagreed with this because they were getting a decaying solution so I began to doubt it